# Retrieve embedded documents from mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

The below data is stored in MongoDB. I am using Spring-Data and storing the data into mongoDB.
If I want to retrieve the fields ("id" or "Name") I can able to do, but if I want to retrieve the sub fields ("firstName" or "lastName")I can't.

(eg.)If I want to retrieve sub field "lastName" from the below data I can't.Kindly help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Data Stored in MongoDB:

```
{

"id":101,

"name": {"firstName":"Mark",

         "lastName":"Antony"

         }
}
```

The Code I am using is:

PersonService.java

```
public List<Audit> searchPerson(Audit audit)
{
List<NameDetails> name=audit.getName();
return mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("name.lastName").is(name.get(0))), Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME); 
}
```

PersonController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public String search(@ModelAttribute Audit audit, ModelMap model) {  
model.addAttribute("personList", personService.searchPerson(audit)); 
return "output";
}
```

Audit.java

```
@Document
public class Audit {
@Id
private String id;
private List<NameDetails> name;

public String getId() {
    System.out.println("Person: getId");
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    System.out.println("Person: setId");
    this.id = id;
}
public List<NameDetails> getName() {
    System.out.println("Audit: getName");
    return name;
}
public void setName(List<NameDetails> name) {
    System.out.println("Audit: setName");
    this.name = name;
}       

}
```

NameDetails.java

```
package com.register.mongo.model;

public class NameDetails {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
System.out.println("NameDetails: setFirstName");
this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
System.out.println("NameDetails: getLastName");
return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
System.out.println("NameDetails: setLastName");
this.lastName = lastName;
}   
}
```

(output.jsp)UI Page

```
<form action="person/search" method="get">
<table>
<tr><td>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"/>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>    

<table border="2">
<c:forEach var="person" items="${personList}">
<tr>
<td>${person.id}</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>${person.lastName}</td> 
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return mongoTemplate.find(
    new Query(Criteria.where("name.lastName").is(name.get(0))), 
    Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME);
```

to

```
return mongoTemplate.find(
    new Query(Criteria.where("name.lastName").is(name.get(0).getLastName())), 
    Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME);
```

You are trying to use the entire `NameDetails` instead of just the last name.

Comment: Thank You for your interest. I have done what you said but it is throwing null pointer exception

Comment: At what line is it throwing the NPE?

Comment: In the return statement. Error in this line: return mongoTemplate.find(
    new Query(Criteria.where("name.lastName").is(name.get(0).getLastName())), 
    Audit.class,COLLECTION_NAME);

Comment: provide stack trace. The only way this could cause an NPE is if mongoTemplate is null, list is empty, or the lastName is null (if `is` throws NPE on null.

Comment: I am passing lastName in textbox from UI and trying to retrieve data, based on lastName. That lastName is not getting set. And if i want to pass id and retrieve only lastName for that id how can I do. I am new to this kindly help me.

Comment: This seems like a different question. Please post it as such fully describing your issue.